# Fade using filter in IE7, IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, opacity, fade

I have the following fade in code that works in IE 9, 10, and other modern browsers to fade in a `<select>` element as it is dynamically added to the page:

```
function fadeIn(element) {        
    var op = 0.1;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (op >=1 ) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        op += 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

I need to make a similar fade work in IE 7 and IE 8. The above code won't work, because those legacy browsers use the `filter` style attribute. So I tried to implement this, but I could not find good documentation. Using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms532990(v=vs.85)), the following is my attempt, using an empty HTML page with just a body tag:

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var body = document.body;
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var optionText = document.createTextNode("A random choice.");
    body.appendChild(select);
    option.appendChild(optionText);
    select.appendChild(option);
    fadeInIE(select);

    function fadeInIE(element) {
        element.style.filter ="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(duration=5)";
        element.filters[0].Apply();
        element.filters[0].Play();
    }
}
```

Other CSS:

```
select {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width:150px;
}
```

It doesn't work. How should I implement `filter` to achieve similar fade in effect?

Comment: what about using the other filter *(alpha(opacity=x)* in your loop ? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: @G-Cyr I have tried including `element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op + ")";` in my loop after I set opacity, but the element becomes invisible with an opacity of 1.099.

Comment: It is weird, because according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395550/setting-opacity-of-dynamically-generated-element-in-ie7 it should work

Comment: OHHH. Opacity values aren't 0-1, they're 0-100 for this!